# How to change Date format without diving to core?

Tags: 7, datetime

I want to convert dates to [Jalali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_calendar) format. The problem is I have to change some of the core files in `/includes` and `/modules`. Is it possible to do this without jumping right into the core?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is [Calendar_Systems](http://drupal.org/project/calendar_systems) module that will not do the core changes but everything else needed on the frontend.

Comment: Thanks but it's in development for D7.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the default timezone for your site at

/admin/config/regional/settings

This will change the output of all dates on your site. You shouldn't have to edit any core files to set your sites timezone.